# Debugging an ajax call after submitting form

Tags: javascript, forms, debugging, validation, firebug

I have a form developed automatically by some php framework. I want to add a custom validation for form inputs and prevent submitting the form if the validation fails.

To do this, I wrote the following script:

```
$("form.pods-form-pod-katilimci").submit(function(event){
    telefon = $("form.pods-form-pod-katilimci #pods-form-ui-pods-field-oncelikli-telefon");
    email = $("form.pods-form-pod-katilimci #pods-form-ui-pods-field-email");
    if( $.trim(telefon.val()).length == 0 && $.trim(email.val()).length == 0) {
        alert("Size ulaşabilmemiz için eposta adresi veya telefon numaranızdan birisini mutlaka doldurmalısınız.");
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

It works properly. There is no problem. But submitting the form triggers an automatic ajax call and that call bypasses my validation.

Therefore, `preventDefault()` can not prevent submitting the form.

I want to find out which javascript function causes this behaviour using Firebug. I looked at the html source of the form but there is no clear sign of a function triggered by submit evend. Since this is an ajax call, I cannot figure out which function is called after form submitting by using "Break on Next" in Firebug.

The form is on this page: http://www.aep.gov.tr/kullanici-islemleri/uyelik-bilgileri/

How can I find out which javascript function is triggered after form submitting.

Comment: In my mind, the form **submit** action is just **submit()** which  without accepting any other parameters or anonymous functions, isn't it? So I think you can not write any procedures as the contents for submitting.

Comment: `submit` function above is not `submit` method of `form` object. It is jquery event handling function for `form.submit`.

Comment: Maybe I am not understanding the action of jQuery submit enough. I am not sure but you may refer the [Official Docs](http://api.jquery.com/submit/) for more information, which indicates that `.submit()` **does not accept any arguments**. There is no arguments in `...submit(function()...`. So I think the event object maybe `this` but not `event` in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the jquery validation plugin:

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

```
$('#yourformId').validate({
  rules:{
     telefon:{
         required:true
     },
     email:{
         required:true
     }
  }
});
```

Then use the ajax-form plugin:
http://malsup.com/jquery/form/

And this code:

```
$('#yourformId').ajaxForm({
   succes:function(response){
      (your code needed for another ajax call)
   }
});
```